# Html and javascript input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to have my input only accept Numbers and the '.', it is working great but it doesn't allow for number pad number keys. I cant seem to find the exact answer online.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ItemTotal#i#" name="ItemTotal#i#" value="#qPriceAct#" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" onkeydown="return keyispressed(event);">
```

JavaScript

```
//prevent , and $ from being input
function keyispressed(e){
    var charval= String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if(isNaN(charval) && (e.which != 8 ) && (e.which != 190 )){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


//is input numeric
function isNumeric (evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode (key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `pattern` attribute? It is a regexp you put inside HTML and it checks validity on its own.

Comment: you mention it's used throughout your web app, is the class `numbersOnly` on each input that should only allow numbers?

Comment: Is "Num-lock" on? ... just in case

Comment: Ye snum lock is on, ive tried both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I believe would be to add a class to all the inputs that only allow numbers. Then you can restrict any input that doesn't match the pattern or a number/decimal.

```js
function numberVerfication(value) {
  var pattern=/^[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]*$/;
  if (value.match(pattern) != null){
    return value
  }
  else {
    var p=/[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]*/;
    return value.match(p)[0];
  }

}
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function(e) {
  e.target.value = numberVerfication(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='numbersOnly' type="text" id="ItemTotal#i#" name="ItemTotal#i#" value="#qPriceAct#">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple using `REGEXP`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class='numbersOnly' id="ItemTotali" name="ItemTotal#i" value="qPriceAct">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
function numValidate(that){
  that.value = that.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');  
}

<input type="text" onkeypress='numValidate(this)' onkeyup='numValidate(this)' class='numbersOnly' id="ItemTotali" name="ItemTotal#i" value="qPriceAct"/>
```

***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/wsumqhwj/1/)***

Comment: yes the problem here is that its used throughout my entire web app. it needs to be within the function and not class or id specific

Comment: @Charles  Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function numberVerfication(value){
         return value.replace(/[^0-9.\-+]/g, '');
 }
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function(e){
      e.target.value=numberVerfication(e.target.value);
});
```